# Allow password authentication in SSH only when there is no key in authorized_keys

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to setup a ssh server that way, that it will accept password authentication only when there is no key added. So when a new user is created he can copy his key by password-based authentication.

Comment: Any hacker will love your arrangement.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae perhaps you should say a bit more to help out our new member.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, it's really small not very used server. Mainly for small personal purposes. But, why it's so bad arrangement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible with pure openssh. But you might be able to make it working using PAM. Conceptually, you should be able to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` a line with

```
password required pam_exec.so /usr/bin/test -s ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I didn't test it, but you should be able to make up missing bits, if some.